# Change input name according to a specific button in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create or import some datas

If data exist, I'm displaying the import button and if didn't exist, displaying the create button.
I'm working with autocomplete (jquery-ui)

So this is my html :

```
    <input name="Test" id="aff" type="text" oninput="onInput(this.value)" class="form-control">
                    
    <button id="create" type="submit" >Create</button>-->
    <button id="import" type="submit" style="display: none">Import</button>
            
</form>
```

I just want to know if is it possible to change name attribute of a input text ?
So, if I click on import the name of input will be :

```
<input  name="Test"
```

And if I click on create the name of input will be :

```
<input  name="Test2"
```

Note: I want use only one input and not 2 input with this two differents names

Anybody can help me and say if it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can change the value of the `name` attribute using the [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method :

```js
$("#btnCreate").click(function(){
  $("#aff_qp").attr("name","affId");
  console.log($("#aff_qp").attr("name"));
});

$("#btnExport").click(function(){
  $("#aff_qp").attr("name","aff[code]");
  console.log($("#aff_qp").attr("name"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="aff_qp" type="text" name="aff[code]" />
<button id="btnCreate">Create</button>
<button id="btnExport">Export</button>
```